# Struggling using pokeapi trying to get description of ability

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, pokeapi

```js
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const Discord = module.require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: "ability",
    aliases: ["abilities"],
    description: "Displays pokedex information for a given pokemon",
    category: "util",
    requiredArgs: ["query"],
    run: async (client, message, args) => {
      
      const query = args.join(" ");
  
      if (!query) {
        return message.channel.send("Try Again This Time With A Pokemon Name");
      }
  
      try {
        const data = await fetch(
          `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/ability/${encodeURIComponent(
            query
          )}`
        ).then((res) => res.json());
        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setDescription(`*${data.flavor_text_entries.flavor_text[1]}*`)
       
       
        message.reply({ embeds: [embed] });
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
        message.reply('NO DATA FOUND')
    }
    
  },
};
```

How can I get the ability description? I didn't found anything about obtaining specific details from the API in docs, so I would appreciate your help!

Comment: Will a structure like this suffice? https://codepen.io/mbacode/pen/OJjBoZN mainly asking because I don't have access to the portions of your code that actually decides the outcome. Such as the `encodeURIComponent`. There is no indication of what kind of response you're getting.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see by looking at their API, you'll get a multidimensional array, which you'll need to *iterate through* in order to fetch the description you need.

A good method in this case is to use the [for in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop, which is optimal, because you can opt to `break` out once you've accessed the value you were looking for.

I can't tell by your question, how you're processing the `data` exactly, so I took the liberty to make my own structure. Feel free to use it, edit it, or do whatever to suit your needs.

Note that the structure of the fetch I am making is dynamic to "some extent", like choosing the ability to describe, as well as what language it should be displayed in.

In my example, I'll use the ability that has the value of `4`, also known as *battle-armor* in their API register. The result will be in English for my example.

When running the snippet,  **wait a few seconds** for the response to go through.

```js
const getDescription = async (value, lang='en') => {
    const dataList = await fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/ability/${value}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
    
    if (dataList) {
        for (const entry in dataList) {
            if (entry === 'flavor_text_entries') { 
                for (const flavor in dataList[`${entry}`]) {
                    if (dataList[`${entry}`][`${flavor}`]['language'].name === `${lang}`) {
                        console.log(dataList[`${entry}`][`${flavor}`].flavor_text);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
    console.log('No data!');
  }
};

getDescription(4, 'en');
```

Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/mbacode/pen/OJjBoZN).